# Question about completeness of the bounded functions as a metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

$(a)$ Let $S$ be a non-empty set (finite or infinite), and consider the space $X = \mathscr{B}(S)$ of all
bounded, real-valued functions on $S$. Define $d_{\infty}$ on S by:

$d_{\infty}(f, g) = \sup_{s\in S}|f(s) − g(s)|$

which is a metric. Show that $(X, d_{\infty})$ is complete.

$(b)$  Consider $\mathcal{C}[−1, 1]$, the space of continuous functions, as a subset of  $X$. Is  $\mathcal{C}[−1, 1]$ closed in $X$?

For (a) i know f is a lipschitz mapping if that helps.

Comment: What is your question? Why did you start by saying that $(X, d_X)$ is a metric space, and then you don't use it anymore? For b), are you assuming that $[-1,1] \subseteq S$?

Comment: i just thought it would help as its in a previous question and im not sure if [-1,1] \subseteq S but apparently (b) can be answered in one sentence

Comment: It seems that in (b) it is implicitly assumed that $S=[-1,1]$. Since a subset  of a complete metric space is closed if and only if it is complete, and $C[-1,1]$ is complete, it is also closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $(X, d_{\infty})$ is complete, pick a Cauchy sequence $\{ f_n\}_n \subseteq X$.
This means that
$$\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists N : \forall n,m \geq N \ \ \ \sup_{s \in S} |f_n(s) - f_m(s)| < \varepsilon$$

In particular this implies that $\forall s \in S$ the sequence $\{ f_n(s) \}_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is Cauchy. But $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, so $\{ f_n(s) \}_n$ is convergent.
Call
$$f(s) = \lim_n f_n(s)$$

In this way you define the pointwise limit of the $f_n$. Now you have to show two things:

1. $f \in X$, i.e. $f$ is bounded
2. $\lim_n d_{\infty}(f_n, f) = 0$, i.e. $f_n$ converges to $f$

This completes the proof, since you show that every Cauchy sequence is convergent.

1. Since $f_n$ is Cauchy, it is a bounded sequence. This means that $\exists L >0$ such that for all $n$ you have $\sup_{s \in S} |f_n(s) - f_1(s)| \leq L$. But now, this implies that for all $s \in S$ you have $|f(s)| \leq L + \sup_S |f_1|$, so $f$ is bounded.
2. $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ let $N$ be such that $\forall n,m \geq N \ \ \sup_{s \in S} |f_n(s) - f_m(s)| < \varepsilon$. Then $\forall n \geq N$

$$d_{\infty} (f, f_n) = $$